# My program crashes(python.exe has stopped working)

Tags: python, eclipse, crash, tkinter

So i've made a project for school, and it won't run and i have no idea why. Everytime i press the "start" button i made, the whole program freezes and stops working, and seeing as i've made a similar program earlier(this one is just much cleaner) i get really confused.
here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.minsize(width=3, height=100)
root.title("Counter")

list=[]
list.append(0)

def counter():
    t = 10
    c = 0
    for row in list:
        if (t < 60) or (c < 5):
            l=Label(root, text=t).grid(row=1, column=c)
            t=10+10
            c=0+1
            list.append(t)
    print("") #This is just for debugging purpose
    for row in list:
        if (t < 110) or (c < 10):
            c=0
            ll=Label(root, text=t).grid(row=2, column=c)
            c=0+1
            t+10
            list.append(t)
    return

label=Label(root, text="...").grid(row=0, column=0)
b=Button(root, text="Start", command=counter).grid(row=0, column=1)
label=Label(root, text="...").grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for all the tips, figured it out due to you! :D

Comment: Using `list` as the name of your own variable is a bad idea. See also assigning the result of `.grid`.

Comment: You're modifying the list you're iterating over. Additionally, the statement `t+10` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're modifying the list you're iterating over. Besides `list` isn't a good name as it shadows the builtin one, you always append an element to your list.
Additionally, none of the conditions will be met since `t` is always assigned to `20` and `c` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is freezing is because you are modifying list while looping over it:

```
list.append(t)
```

You did that twice. You can not do it in this manner and you should either use a separate list to carry out whatever you were trying to do or some sort of list iterator. Also as already noted,

```
 t+10
```

has no affect and you should not be naming your list "list" anyways since it is a reserved word for a different purpose.